# How to hook into react-final-form updates?

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I'd like to hook into react-final-form's updates. Is that possible? Namely, I'd like to be able to execute an arbitrary function that will update the data that react-final-form is in charge of. In particular, I have a `Model` class with an `update` method, and I'd like to be able to call `instance.update({ [fieldName]: fieldValue })` instead of updating the plain ol' Javascript object that react-final-form uses. Is this possible?

An example of what I'd like to do is as follows:

```js
<Form
  initialValue={myModel} // instance of Model
  render={() => <SomeField name="height" />}
  updated={(values, name, value) => values.update({ [name]: value })}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutators props as below"

```
mutators={{
  setFieldUpdate: () => {
    ........
  }
  /** Example
  setFieldUpdate: (args, state) => {
    const [name, touched = true] = args;
    const field = state.fields[name];
    ........
  }
  */
}}
```

and the  render props 「form」provided

form.mutators.setFieldUpdate(${YourFieldName}, ${YouWantedChangeInputValue}

in your render

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your use case, but perhaps something like the [Declarative Form Rules example](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#declarative-form-rules) might be what you need?